# how to add to value in a single array in php

Tags: php, arrays

please someone will guide me to how to add the values of below conditions and then update the added value in code .

how to sum value of where code =low_order_fee and where code= goods_total then update the sum value in where code=goods_total.

```
  Array
    (
     [0] => Array
       (
        [order_total_id] => 999
        [order_id] => 194
        [code] => goods_total
        [title] => Goods-Total
        [text] => £130.00
        [value] => 130.0000
        [sort_order] => 1
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [order_total_id] => 1000
        [order_id] => 194
        [code] => low_order_fee
        [title] => * Carriage
        [text] => £10.00
        [value] => 10.0000
        [sort_order] => 3
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [order_total_id] => 1001
        [order_id] => 194
        [code] => sub_total
        [title] => Sub-Total
        [text] => £130.00
        [value] => 130
        [sort_order] => 4
    )

[3] => Array
    (
        [order_total_id] => 1002
        [order_id] => 194
        [code] => tax
        [title] => VAT (20%)
        [text] => £26.00
        [value] => 26.0000
        [sort_order] => 5
    )

[4] => Array
    (
        [order_total_id] => 1003
        [order_id] => 194
        [code] => total
        [title] => Invoice Total
        [text] => £166.00
        [value] => 166.0000
        [sort_order] => 9
    )
```

)

Comment: Can't even able to understand your question what you want

Comment: Please elaborate your question. Where did you get stuck . Here only I understand is `where`

Answer (score 1):

A rudimentary solution:

```
foreach ($array_var as $key => $item) {
    if ($item['code'] == 'low_order_fee') {
        $first_val = $item['value'];
    }
    if ($item['goods_total'] == 'low_order_fee') {
        $sec_val = $item['value'];
        $position = $key;
    }
}
$array_var[$position]['goods_total'] = $first_val + $sec_val;
```

But maybe you should think about store the values in another way to make easier access to them.

I hope it helps.